# Python 3.9 не считает сумму списка чисел

Tags: python

```
>>> l = list(map(int, input().split()))
1 2 3 4
>>> sum(l)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> sum(l)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Функции min и max работают.

```
>>> min(l)
1
>>> max(l)
4
```

Comment: На моей стороне все работает. Python3.9

Comment: И где-то ранее в консоли у вас наверняка есть что-то вроде `sum = ...`

Comment: Очень возможно.

Comment: Не используйте имена встроенных классов и функций для своих объектов!

Comment: Попробуйте `__builtins__.sum(l)`

Answer (score 5):

Проблема (`bug`) возникает из-за того, что где-то выше в вашем коде вы объявили переменную `sum` и присвоили ей целочисленное (`int`) значение. Например: `sum = 123` После этого любая попытка вызвать встроенную функцию `sum([10, 11, 12])` будет интерпретирована как следующий вызов:

```
123([10, 11, 12])
```

и вы получите соответствующее сообщение об ошибке - о том что целое число не является объектом, который можно вызывать как функцию.

Воспроизведение ошибки:

```
In [78]: lst = [10, 11, 12]

In [79]: sum(lst)  # <-- встроенная функция `sum()` работает правильно
Out[79]: 33

In [80]: sum = 123    # NOTE: не делайте так!!!

In [81]: sum(lst)  # <-- тот же самый вызов `sum()` не работает после переопределения `sum`
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-de86c5632935> in <module>
----> 1 sum(lst)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score -1):

Перезагрузка решила эту проблему. Не подумал о возможной проблеме со стороны платформы. Баг возник на Mac OS Catalina.

Comment: Баг не в в MacOS, а в том что вы используете зарезервированные слова (sum) в качестве имён переменных! После присваивания “sum = ...”, встроенной функцией sum() невозможно воспользоваться. Не используйте зарезервированные в Python слова и не придётся перегружать систему / Python.

Comment: Вот так пользователи без должного навыка логического размышления находят баги сначала в Python, затем в платформе и, наконец, во Вселенной...